# For Apache Spark is there a Front-End that is recommended

Tags: linux, gui, ubuntu

Besides the built-in web interface for Apache Spark, are there front-ends that are recommended for Linux, like Ubuntu 16.04, to simplify the interface and/or have an interface that is more notebook based like kaggle.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question looks like Jupyter Notebook https://jupyter.org would do the job and is certainly Kaggle like.